# Group matched patterns in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have the following code of a type Enum, which contains many value types.

```
data Enum = A1 | A2 | B1 | B2 | B3 | C1 | .. | Z1 | Z2

foo :: Enum -> AnyType
foo A1 = foo1 A1
foo A2 = foo2 A2
foo B1 = foo1 B1
foo B2 = foo2 B2
foo B3 = foo3 B3
foo C1 = foo1 C1
...
foo Z1 = foo1 Z1
foo Z2 = foo2 Z2
```

This looks very verbose. If I group them [using guard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7604046/490815), I cannot rely on the compiler to help check value types are exhaustive (e.g., missing `Z1`), which is covered by `otherwise` be default. Also groups can contain duplicates(e.g., [A1, B1, ..] and [A1, B2]). Is there any way to group patterns while also having the compiler check for missing and duplicate patterns?

```
foo x | x `elem` [A1, B1, C1 {-- ..., Z1, --}] = foo1 x
      | x `elem` [A2, B2] = foo2 x
      | x `elem` [B3] = foo1 x 
      | otherwise = defaultFoo x
```

Comment: Does it have to be a single enum type or are you allowed to choose the representation?

Comment: Any representation is allowed, as long as it gets the job done.

Answer (score 4):

I would propose that you make your data structure reflect the programming structure you plan to compute on.

```
data OneOf2 = OneOf2 | TwoOf2
data OneOf3 = OneOf3 | TwoOf3 | ThreeOf3
data Has2 = A | C | ... | Z
data Has3 = B | ...
data Enum = Group2 Has2 OneOf2 | Group3 Has3 OneOf3
```

You may now match something like this:

```
foo x = case x of
    Group2 _ OneOf2 -> foo1 x
    Group2 _ TwoOf2 -> foo2 x
    Group3 _ OneOf3 -> foo1 x
    Group3 _ TwoOf3 -> foo2 x
    Group3 _ ThreeOf3 -> foo3 x
```

Answer (score 2):

A definition like this is somewhat syntactically simpler:

```
bar :: Enum -> Enum -> AnyType
bar x = case x of

  A1 -> foo1
  B1 -> foo1
  C1 -> foo1

  A2 -> foo2
  B2 -> foo2

  B3 -> foo3
```

Then `foo` can be defined as:

```
foo :: Enum -> AnyType
foo = join bar
```